# How the browser input type=number spinner works?

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to replicate the functionality of the spinner I get when I create input type=number.

```html
<input type=number step=0.3/>
```

In this case, clicking on the upper spinner increases the value by 0.3 (0.3, 0.6 , 0.9 , 1.2 , 1.5 ...etc).

But when the value of the `input` field is 1.4 and I click on the increase button the value changes to 1.5
so the increasementis only by 0.1, and when the value of the input field is 1.3 the increasement is by 0.2.
My question how to work out how much the current value increase to match the closest step increment?!

Here is my attempt

```js
export class Spinner { 
        increase(currentValue, step) {
           const step = step || 1;
           const decimalSize = getDecimalSize(step);
           const current = normalize(currentValue, decimalSize);
           const ratio = Math.ceil(normalize(current / step, decimalSize));
           let increment = normalize(ratio * step, decimalSize);
         
        if (
            normalize(current % step, decimalSize) === 0 ||
            current === increment ||
            normalize(current % step, decimalSize) === 1
        ) {
            increment = normalize(current + step, decimalSize);
        }
    }
}

export function getDecimalSize(value: number) {
    if (Math.floor(value) === value) return 0;
    return value.toString().split(".")[1]?.length || 0;
}

export function normalize(value: number, decimalSize: number): number {
    decimalSize = decimalSize || 1;
   const n = Math.pow(10, decimalSize + 1);
   return Math.round(value * n) / n;
}
```

This works fine for positive numbers, but it does not work well with negative numbers

for example if the current value is `-2` and step is `0.3` I get `-1.8` instead of `-1.7`

Answer (score 0):

From the [HTML Standard](https:////html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number))

> When the element is suffering from a step mismatch, the user agent may
> round the element's value to the nearest number for which the element
> would not suffer from a step mismatch. If there are two such numbers,
> user agents are encouraged to pick the one nearest positive infinity.

Your user-agent (~browser) is likely rounding the step to avoid a mismatch. It goes from 1.4 to 1.5 because 1.5 is exactly 5 steps from 0, while 1.7 would be 5.666 steps away. Same reasoning goes for negative numbers, 1.8 is divisible by 0.3 while 1.7 isn't.

Note that in the first case, 1.8 would be a closer rounding than 1.5, and that goes against the specification. These things happen and it's possible it will change in the future.

I haven't tried it but I imagine it is possible you'd get different results in some other browsers.